# Can't figure out why my javascript isnt working

Tags: javascript

Questions is I have a javascript that looks at a couple text fields and gets the values of each. adds them together and gives me a total in my scrap text field. What I would like to do is say is if setup is A B C or D do sum if the value for setup is blank do other. it seems to not want to work any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.scrap').click(function() {
    var weld_scrap = $('.weld').val();
    var dim_scrap = $('.dim').val();
    var visual_scrap = $('.visual').val();
    var adjust_scrap = $('.adjust').val();
    var setup = $('.setup').val();
    console.log(setup)
    var sum = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap) + parseInt(setup);
    var other = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap);
    var A = '10';
    var B = '10';
    var C = '10';
    var D = '10';
    if (setup == 'A') {
      setup = A;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'B') {
      setup = B;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'C') {
      setup = C;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'D') {
      setup = D;
          $('.scrap').val(sum);
    }else if (setup == '') {
       $('.scrap').val(other);

    }
  });
});
```

I also tried this for if setup is blank

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.scrap').click(function() {
    var weld_scrap = $('.weld').val();
    var dim_scrap = $('.dim').val();
    var visual_scrap = $('.visual').val();
    var adjust_scrap = $('.adjust').val();
    var setup = $('.setup').val();
    console.log(setup)
    var sum = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap) + parseInt(setup);
    var other = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap);
    var A = '10';
    var B = '10';
    var C = '10';
    var D = '10';
    if (setup == 'A') {
      setup = A;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'B') {
      setup = B;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'C') {
      setup = C;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'D') {
      setup = D;
          $('.scrap').val(sum);
    }else if (setup === null) {
       $('.scrap').val(other);

    }
  });
});
```

and this as well

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.scrap').click(function() {
    var weld_scrap = $('.weld').val();
    var dim_scrap = $('.dim').val();
    var visual_scrap = $('.visual').val();
    var adjust_scrap = $('.adjust').val();
    var setup = $('.setup').val();
    console.log(setup)
    var sum = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap) + parseInt(setup);
    var other = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap);
    var A = '10';
    var B = '10';
    var C = '10';
    var D = '10';
    if (setup == 'A') {
      setup = A;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'B') {
      setup = B;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'C') {
      setup = C;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'D') {
      setup = D;
          $('.scrap').val(sum);
    }else if (setup == '0') {
       $('.scrap').val(other);

    }
  });
});
```

this too...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.scrap').click(function() {
    var weld_scrap = $('.weld').val();
    var dim_scrap = $('.dim').val();
    var visual_scrap = $('.visual').val();
    var adjust_scrap = $('.adjust').val();
    var setup = $('.setup').val();
    console.log(setup)
    var sum = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap) + parseInt(setup);
    var other = parseInt(weld_scrap) + parseInt(dim_scrap) + parseInt(visual_scrap) + parseInt(adjust_scrap);
    var A = '10';
    var B = '10';
    var C = '10';
    var D = '10';
    if (setup == 'A') {
      setup = A;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'B') {
      setup = B;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'C') {
      setup = C;
         $('.scrap').val(sum);

    }else if (setup == 'D') {
      setup = D;
          $('.scrap').val(sum);
    }else if (setup === undefined) {
       $('.scrap').val(other);

    }
  });
});
```

Comment: can you add a demo ?

Comment: You can use https://jsfiddle.net/ for a demo

Comment: What does "it seems to not want to work" mean?

Comment: please provide demo or html code

Comment: " it seems to not want to work" - holy crap, javascript has become sentient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the value is empty from the start otherwise check if its equal 'A' OR 'B' ....

```
if( setup.match(/\S/)){
  if (setup == 'A') {
    setup = A;
       $('.scrap').val(sum);

  }else if (setup == 'B') {
    setup = B;
       $('.scrap').val(sum);

  }else if (setup == 'C') {
    setup = C;
       $('.scrap').val(sum);

  }else if (setup == 'D') {
    setup = D;
        $('.scrap').val(sum);
  }
}else{
  // will come here when there is an empty value 
  $('.scrap').val(other);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately its still not working  if setup has something in it 'A' it will not get sum value same goes if it is blank as well. @mohamed-ibrahim

Comment: @Snowman1234 i modified the code there was an extra ! in my code, so let me explain what is going here, \S match Any non-whitespace character and so if its empty value then it will not match and for that will go to else.

Answer (score -1):

Check if you have imported correct jquery header . While you can use .on() method and check it .. 
It is good to check step by step from start while developing with console.log().

```
$( ".scrap" ).on( "click", function() {
    // your stuff here 
   );
});
```